# Include dependencies in Maven assembly without include the actual artifact

Tags: java, maven, build

I would like to create a Maven assembly that contains the transitive dependencies of an artifact without actually including the artifact itself. I have tried to exclude the artifact from the assembly, but then its dependencies aren't included as a result.

ArtifactA has DependencyA, DependencyB

Assembly should contain DependencyA, DependencyB (without ArtifactA)

And I would preferrably like to do this without having to explicitly specifiy what dependencies to be included in the assembly because this will be done with multiple projects that have many dependencies.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you change the goal for the assembly to before the jar is built?

Comment: This feels kinda round-a-bout/counter-intuitive.  What if ArtifactA has a release where they eliminate their dependency on A? Will your project break? If you depend on A and B, why not just put them in your POM directly?

Comment: Sorry for not providing more context. I am migrating our web apps to use JBoss AS 7, which now has a concept of modules that are used to place jar files and other files on the classpath. I am trying to create a Maven project that will build the JBoss module to include the dependencies for our API jar, so that all of its dependencies will not be included in each war that uses it.

Comment: I am trying to keep from changing things up any more drastically than I have already had to and can't have the API jar itself under the JBoss modules folder because it is used by several other third party apps that don't depend on those dependencies. Only the war files need those dependencies, which I am making available to JBoss. Yes, I realize this is a maintenance nightmare, but with a distributed team I am making the changes when I can to move to more reasonable application layout.

Comment: That sound like a dependency with scope "provided". Which confuses me why you are using maven-assembly ? Is this project an EAR ?

Comment: Provided causes the dependency to not even be evaluated for inclusion in an assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. This will produce an artifact that only contains the dependencies of the depende

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>moduletest</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduletest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dependency</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

assembly.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>module</id>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>dependency:dependency</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

Comment: Nice, but this would get the transitive dependencies of all artifacts in the project, not just the `dependency:dependency` one